# How to do a partial text (query_string) match on a nested array of texts?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to do a partial or subword matching on a nested field that is an array of strings?

I have indexed documents that have a nested field which contains an array of texts, eg:

```
"entities":[
   "0":{
      "id":13,
      "tags":[
         "0":"some other class of tag may be present"
      ]
   }
]
```

Entities field is indexed as a "nested" type with "tags" property. "tags" is "keyword" type that has a field "lower_case" of type text and case_insensitive analyzer.

With a nested query_string that contains the full value text I can get a match:

```
{
   "query":{
      "nested":{
         "query":{
            "bool":{
               "must":[
                  {
                     "query_string":{
                        "query":"some other class of tag may be present",
                        "fields":[
                           "entities.tags.lower_case"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "path":"entities"
      }
   }
}
```

But when I try to use a partial matching (eg. "some other" or "class") I don't get a match. Is there a way to do partial matching on nested arrays in elasticsearch?

EDIT:
Mapping done in java:

```
XContentBuilder docProperties = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
docProperties
.startObject( "entities" )
   .field("type", "nested")
   .startObject("properties")
        .startObject( "tags" )
           .field("type", "keyword")
           .startObject("fields")
                  .startObject( "lower_case" )
                      .field("type", "text")
                      .field("analyzer", "case_insensitive")
                  .endObject()
              .endObject()
          .endObject()
      .endObject()
.endObject();
```

Comment: Can you post your mapping ?

Comment: And what's the verison of ES ?

Comment: I've added the mapping done with Java. It's elastic version 6.2.

Comment: show the analyzer case_insensitive

Comment: {
  "analysis": {
    "analyzer": {
      "case_insensitive": {
        "tokenizer": "keyword",
        "filter": [
          "lowercase"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
"settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "case_insensitive": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You should not use keyword tokenizer.

```
The keyword tokenizer is a “noop” tokenizer that accepts whatever text it is given and outputs the exact same text as a single term
```